Changes to Word 365 document not retained
This is my first post. I have had a lengthy break (8y) from working in document production and am trying to get to grips with MS365 (Business Premium Licence).  I'm feel I'm losing my mind, because I'm finding that changes to formatting in documents are not being retained.  The latest example is that I changed the font size of the normal style in a document (and I know I did it, because I emailed my boss last week to let her know), yet when I accessed the document again today, the style has reverted to the original font size.  This is just the latest in a line of issues I've experienced.  We use Teams as document management, and I'm convinced that when other users access the documents to review in Teams view or Edge (I exclusively open docs in the desktop app), it's having an impact on the document layout, but I feel there's something else at play here. I'm not sure if it's something to do with AutoSave, or preserving fidelity settings, or something else I'm entirely unaware of - there have been a LOT of developments while I've been gone!
Another issue is as below where the same page on two different machines displays differently as per the images attached.
graphics/text boxes spaced graphics/text boxes displaced
Please help me save my sanity!  Any and all information/suggestions will be gratefully received.
Thanks in Advance,
Violet
